# Make UITableview selected after view is disappear

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, uitableview

I created a music playlist with tableview like this :

[image]

When user touch a cell music plays and cell resizes, I need to make table view remain selected when view controller is disappeared  . Is there any possible way to force table view selected or unchanged when view is dismissed or disappeared ?

Code :

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! TrackCell

        if selectedCellIndexPath != nil && selectedCellIndexPath == indexPath as NSIndexPath! {

            selectedCellIndexPath = nil

            stopSong()
            cell.playImage.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Play")
            isPlaying = false


        } else  {

            selectedCellIndexPath = indexPath as NSIndexPath!
            cell.playImage.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Pause")

            isPlaying = true

            playSong(name: cell.trackName.text!)

            timer  = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.1, target: self, selector: #selector(MusicViewController.updateDuration), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        }


        tableView.beginUpdates()
        tableView.endUpdates()

        if selectedCellIndexPath != nil {

            tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .none, animated: true)

        }
```

**EDIT 1**

```
var player = AVAudioPlayer()



func playSong(name:String)  {

    //Get current index path
    let indexPath:IndexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath as IndexPath) as! TrackCell

    let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource:name , withExtension: "mp3")!

    do {

        player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)

        //get slider value from music duration
        cell.slider.maximumValue = Float(player.duration)
        cell.slider.minimumValue = 0.0

        let playerIsPlaying:Bool = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "playerIsPlaying")
        if playerIsPlaying == false {

            player.prepareToPlay()
            player.play()

        } else {

            print("music is playing ")
        }


    } catch let error as NSError {

        print(error.description)
    }


         timer  = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.1, target: self, selector: #selector(MusicViewController.updateDuration), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}




    func stopSong()  {

        player.stop()

        //stop slider update
        timer.invalidate()
    }
```

Comment: For this are you calling an API or locally manage?

Comment: @GouravJoshi no everything is locally , musics plays from device.

Comment: @Mc.Lover Which  view controller is disappeared ?

Comment: funnily enough there is a call **"clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear"** - read up on it in the manual.  hope it helps.

Comment: You need to store the values in defaults when didSelectRowAtIndex calls and when you will again come on that view, these defaults value used in heightForRow method, and height will manage and other things will be managed by defaults.

Comment: @GouravJoshi I did something like this , but the problem is when programmatically  select a cell music plays again ! ! !

Comment: You mean that if a music play upto 1 min ok, now you navigate to another screen and when you again come that music play from starting correct?

Comment: You should manage color selection manually rather than default selection color , You don't need to select cell again after storing in defaults , just fetch that indexpath and assign to `selectedCellIndexPath` after that when you reload data , then cell for row you just change contentview background color

Answer (score 1):

Try to save the `IndexPath` selected in a global variable. Then in you viewAppears select the cell a that `IndexPath`.

For example :

```
var selectedIndexPath : IndexPath? = nil

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet var tableView : UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        self.tableView.selectRow(at: selectedIndexPath, animated: animated, scrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.none)
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        selectedIndexPath = indexPath
    }
}
```

#### EDIT 1

In the music plays again, you should check in the function `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell` if the cell's music is playing or not.
If it is, you could give to this cell you Selected UI.

Try something like that :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "YouCellIdentifier", for: indexPath) as? YourCellClass{

            if cell.music.isPlaying{

                //Selected style
            }else{

                //Normal style
            }
            return cell
        }
        return UITableViewCell()
    }
```

Hope it helps.

Here you can download a concrete example:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2RAeG6eqtvCSWNVeDIzU3ZKc3M/view?usp=sharing

Comment: This makes music play again  !

Comment: Is it possible that when I will come again on that screen then selected view will be appear as it is ?

Comment: Will you please share the project ...?

Comment: No problem, here you have a concrete example: [link]https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2RAeG6eqtvCSWNVeDIzU3ZKc3M/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Thank you so much it's very nice of you, but the main problem is when I play the music , and diss miss the view music is still playing but I have no control on it ! for example i cannot stop it when View did load again ! I add music code , please have a look

Comment: Ok your problem is that when you play the song you instantiate a new AVAudioPlayer. You should create a singleton that stores your AVAudioPlayer. In order to be able to to get it again when you view appears and have the control.